# interfacing the pmodad7193 to raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3

I want to interface the raspberry pi with pmodAd7193. but the pmodad7193 or ad7193 library is not on the internet. can you refer me where i can download it.. and how can install to my raspberry pi and also give me some idea to what to do in next step.I watch all video lesson regarding analog to digital converter but didn't understand what to do in this case

Comment: see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83345/interface-ad7193-with-raspberry-pi

Comment: i already see this link problem is still occuring

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/configuring.md  i am going through this link to make menu config.. ibut when i am going through ( $ make bcmrpi_defconfig) in both local building and cross compiling for preparing the configure to kernel it shows error (make :*** no rule to make target '"bcrmpi_defconfig".Stop)..

or is this link is write to make menu config..